# Duda general con código de GitHub para APP IOS

Tags: ios, github, app

Tengo un par de dudas generales sobre el código de GitHub. A ver si podéis ayudarme.

Mi primera pregunta es, que es licencia MIT? es decir es libre? puedes modificar el código? etc etc

Y mi segunda duda es, una vez instalo el código en mi APP, si el propietario hace algún tipo de modificación, se me vería reflejado en mi código? quiero decir, si de alguna manera está conectado y "su" cambio para a mi código?

Como véis es una duda bastante general...

Espero que me podáis ayudar.

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas,

**Licencia MIT**

Sobre la licencia MIT decirte que puedes utilizar el código sin ningún problema, editarlo, ponerlo a la venta como desees, con la única condición de que debes poner en el software el copyright junto con el año y el autor (a parte de no utilizarlo con fines delictivos). Puedes leer más en este enlace a la wikipedia [Link wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licencia_MIT)

**Cambios reflejados desde GitHub**

Eso que comentas no es posible, puesto que tú te bajas el código, lo modificas o utilizas como quieres y lo compilas para generar tu software. Si cualquier cambio que el autor realizase se reflejase en tu software, éste podría quedar inutilizado. Por lo tanto debes descargarte el código fuente de nuevo y realizar los cambios pertinentes.

Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: Muchas Gracias Héctor!

Comment: @Yayo Es un placer, te recomendaría, si vas a trabajar en este mundo, que te hagas algún tutorial de git (control de versiones del código). Ya que te será esencial, y a la larga te ahorrará mucho tiempo, ya que podrás tener varias versiones del código, hacer pruebas y cambiar lo que quieras sin tener que estar copiando y pegando carpetas. Saludos!!

Comment: Hola de nuevo! Una duda más que seguro que tú puedes conectestarme...una vez tengo código escrito en el XCode, cuando yo hago un commit changes, ¿a dónde van esos cambios? es decir ¿donde está ese repositorio? ¿cómo tengo acceso a él? ¿qué diferencia hay con crear un repositorio con el git?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Yayo Buenas de nuevo, según las normas de StackOverflow debes crear una pregunta nueva, aún así te la respondo por aquí. Cuando haces un commit, los cambios que has hecho se te quedan en local (en tu disco duro), entonces puedes tener varias versiones del código en tu disco duro. Tras haber hecho los commit, tienes la opción de realizar un Push, que es enviar el código a un servidor remoto. GitHub y Bitbucket te permiten tener repositorios gratuitos, en los que guardar tu código. Obviamente esto último es lo que recomendado, ya que si pierdes el disco duro, perderás todo. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

La licencia MIT es una licencia de software que te permite reutilizar el código. Puedes modificarlo a tu gusto y hacer lo que quieras con él.

Sin embargo, lo que dices de que el propietario haga alguna modificación y se vea reflejado en lo que tu ya has instalado me temo que no es posible, si el cambia algo del código en su github y tu quieres que se vea reflejado debes volver a obtener el código y/o modificarlo a tu necesidad.

Fuente: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licencia_MIT)

Comment: Muchas gracias Orz!

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la "licencia MIT", hay que aclarar que es un término ambiguo, porque hay diferentes licencias creadas por el MIT, pero generalmente se suelen referir a ésta:

> Copyright <YEAR> <COPYRIGHT HOLDER>
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Traducción al español (sin validez legal):

> Copyright (c) <año> <titular del copyright>
>
> Se concede permiso, de
>   forma gratuita, a cualquier persona que obtenga una copia de este
>   software y de los archivos de documentación asociados (el "Software"),
>   para utilizar el Software sin restricción, incluyendo sin limitación
>   los derechos a usar, copiar, modificar, fusionar, publicar,
>   distribuir, sublicenciar, y/o vender copias del Software, y a permitir
>   a las personas a las que se les proporcione el Software a hacer lo
>   mismo, sujeto a las siguientes condiciones: El aviso de copyright
>   anterior y este aviso de permiso se incluirán en todas las copias o
>   partes sustanciales del Software. EL SOFTWARE SE PROPORCIONA "TAL
>   CUAL", SIN GARANTÍA DE NINGÚN TIPO, EXPRESA O IMPLÍCITA, INCLUYENDO
>   PERO NO LIMITADO A GARANTÍAS DE COMERCIALIZACIÓN, IDONEIDAD PARA UN
>   PROPÓSITO PARTICULAR Y NO INFRACCIÓN. EN NINGÚN CASO LOS AUTORES O
>   TITULARES DEL COPYRIGHT SERÁN RESPONSABLES DE NINGUNA RECLAMACIÓN,
>   DAÑOS U OTRAS RESPONSABILIDADES, YA SEA EN UNA ACCIÓN DE CONTRATO,
>   AGRAVIO O CUALQUIER OTRO MOTIVO, QUE SURJA DE O EN CONEXIÓN CON EL
>   SOFTWARE O EL USO U OTRO TIPO DE ACCIONES EN EL SOFTWARE.

Sobre el funcionamiento de GitHub (o cualquier otro repositorio de versiones que uses):

Los usuarios (en este caso los desarrolladores, por ejemplo tú) que usen el código tienen (activamente) que actualizar el código de su copia local para obtener los últimos cambios. Si quisieses reflejar en tu aplicación la última versión del repositorio, tendrías que obtener el códido fuente (git pull) y unirlo con el tuyo (hacer un "merge", en el caso de que hubieses modificado ese código tú también). Tras eso tendría que crear una nueva versión de tu aplicación y distribuirla (ponerla en la tienda). Sólo entonces tus usuarios podrían actualizar y recibir los cambios.